# XmlDocument not performing validation?

Tags: c#, xml, validation

I have this function for validate xml messages against external schema file:

```
private bool IsValidMessage(string message, XmlDocument xDoc)
{   
    this.valid = true;

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    ms.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;                                


    XmlReaderSettings xSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    xSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

    xSettings.Schemas = new System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet();
    xSettings.Schemas.Add(null, "message.xsd");
    xSettings.ValidationEventHandler += delegate(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e) {
        this.valid = false;
        ShowMessage("Wrong message format: " + message);
    };

    XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(ms, xSettings);                                                                    
    xDoc.Load(xReader);                                                     
    return valid;
}
```

When I call IsValidMesage("nothing", xDoc); it returns true and code in validationEventHandler delegate never executes...(load throws exception but i think it should be taken care of in the delegate...) Do you have any idea why?

Comment: can you try putting this 

while (xReader.Read());

after your XMLReader.Create line. see if it executes your EventHandler

Answer (score 0):

Think I found the reason, but this is only my guess:

When in string that should represent a proper xml document is just some string (like "nothing" in example) the validation would not happen becouse load throws exception that this isn't an xml at all.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162371.aspx

I think you need to do:

```
xmlDoc.Validate(eventhandler);
```